# How to perform read and seek in one command python?

Tags: python-3.x

instead on writing
can we write this in one command

`f=open('spiderman.txt','w')
f.seek(2)
f.read()'

The seek and read command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must change mode to reading by removing `'w'` argument, that opens your file for writing.

```
with open('spiderman.txt') as f:
    f.seek(2)
    text = f.read()
```

Secondly, you can use slices to cut off your text ([Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation))

```
with open('spiderman.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()[2:]
```